# NSURLRequest / NSURLConnection ios 5.0 v/s earlier versions

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, ios5

I am trying to use NSMutableRequest and NSURLConnection to fetch a compressed file from the server . Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadUrl
                                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                          timeoutInterval:30.0];


[newRequest setValue:@"Y29tLm5vbWFkZ......" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:newRequest delegate:self];
if (!connection) {
        [self handleDownloadError];
}
```

And I am using the same NSURLConnectionDelegate method

```
didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData, connectionDidFinishLoading, didFailWithError
```

But, I am getting different responses when I run this code in ios 4.3 or earlier version (it downloads the zipped file) and ios 5.0 ( returns a JSON saying "Authentication Failure.").

ios 5.0 has introduced many new methods for NSURLConnectionDelegate. But I am not sure if this is an issue regarding changed api for ios 5.0 or it's the server code that is handling the same request in different ways. Does anyone know what may be the problem ?

Comment: No one who can help you with this can talk about it since iOS5 is still covered by an NDA. You might want to try Apples Developer Forums.

Comment: I am not sure if the issue is because of changes in ios 5 or it's server issue. thanks anyways

Comment: You need to examine the exact HTTP header sent from your simulator on ios4.3 and ios5. If they are identical, then it's server's responsibility to stop treating the devices differently.

Answer (score 3):

iOS5 changed the way HTTP headers are capitalized, also removed spaces at least from end. Verify what is the actual HTTP headers you receive by printing them into console:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection
  didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse
{
  NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)aResponse;
  NSLog(@"Response headers :%@", [httpResponse allHeaderFields]);
}
```

Btw did you notice that those methods you're listing are marked as "*Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3*" at the Apple [iOS Developer Library docs for NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-387826)?

Comment: There is an as-yet-undocumented protocol that your delegate should conform to: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.  It is in the headers but is not yet documented.  Seems they're half way done converting this informal protocol over to a formal one.  All the same methods are there, just defined differently.